# Fast hill climbing algorithm that can stabilize when near optimal

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, hill-climbing

I have a floating point number `x` from `[1, 500]` that generates a binary `y` of `1` at some probability `p`. And I'm trying to find the `x` that can generate the most `1` or has highest `p`. I'm assuming there's only one maximum.

Is there a algorithm that can converge fast to the `x` with highest `p` while making sure it doesn't jump around too much after it's achieved for e.x. within 0.1% of the optimal `x`? Specifically, it would be great if it stabilizes when near < 0.1% of optimal `x`.

I know we can do this with simulated annealing but I don't think I should hard code temperature because I need to use the same algorithm when `x` could be from `[1, 3000]` or the `p` distribution is different.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=988711) provides an for smart hill-climbing algorithm. The idea is  basically you take n samples as starting points. The algorithm is as follows (it is simplified into one dimensional for your problem):

1. Take `n` sample points in the search space. In the paper, he uses Linear Hypercube Sampling since the dimensions of the data in the paper is assumed to be large. In your case, since it is one-dimensional, you can just use random sapling as usual.
2. For each sample points, gather points from its "local neighborhood" and find a best fit quadratic curve. Find the new maximum candidate from the quadratic curve. If the objective function of the new maximum candidate is actually higher than the previous one, update the sample point to the new maximum candidate. Repeat this step with smaller "local neighborhood" size for each iteration.
3. Use the best point from the sample points
4. Restart: repeat step 2 and 3, and then compare the maximums. If there is no improvement, stop. If there is improvement, repeat again.